# other computers on the same domain cannot connect to my local WebSphere server

Tags: localhost, websphere, local-network

I have a WebSphere Application server running on my local Windows machine.  but other computers on the same domain cannot access my WebSphere server.  They can ping my machine but when I try

```
http://myworkstation.domain.com:9080/testApplication
or
http://myworkstation:9080/testApplication
```

all of them will just try to connect for awhile and give up with the messages like

```
"Make sure web address http://myworkstation:9080 is correct"
```

and the server log on my machine does even indicate anything is trying to access.  odd.  I am not a WebSphere or network guru so I am getting lost and my Sys Admin is not good at WebSphere either.

I even tried the ip address of my machine and still same thing
I appreciate any advice or direction to the solution / workaround.

thanks

Comment: Likely just a local or network firewall issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the ports were blocked by administrators for security reasons.  If you are in the similar situation, check your firewall and anti-virus programs.